# Absolute/Relative path to files in Eclipse

Tags: java, relative-path

I am working on an assignment where I need to use an `XML` file in the project. The file is currently in a folder I created called `res`. The `res` folder is simply under the project folder. `myproject --> res --> myxmlfile.xml`

The `.java` file calling this `xml` file is in the `src` folder. `myproject --> JavaResources --> src --> edu.unsw.comp9321.assignment1(package) --> myjavafile.java`

I was wondering how should I refer to this file in my Java code if I also want this code to work when I run the project on another computer?

When I use a relative path it appears to be searching from the folder where Eclipse is installed, as opposed to the `workspace` folder where the project exists.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
File fXmlFile = new File("C:/Users/Giridhaar/workspace/COMP9321Assignment1/res/xml/musicDb.xml");
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this android project?

Comment: Hi Libin. No, its a `Dynamic Web Project`.

Comment: can you paste the piece of code where you are referring the file?

Comment: so that's absolute path... not relative

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to do relative path. As I said above, it seems to search the incorrect folder.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

```
File fXmlFile = new File("res/xml/musicDb.xml");
```

Comment: I get the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Giridhaar\Desktop\eclipse-java-helios-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\res\xml\musicDb.xml`

Comment: ohh.. so res is not a part of your project?

Comment: My `workspace` folder is in a different location to where Eclipse is installed. In the `workspace` folder, `res` exists. `/workspace/COMP9321Assignment1/res/xml/musicDb.xml`

Comment: then you can't give a relative path. When you run on another computer, the file won't be migrated. You can to manually copy it there along with same folder structure. If the xml is inside your project, it goes along with the build when you want it to run on another computer. And in that case relative path works.

Comment: Thanks GV. The `xml` file is in my project so how do I use a relative path?

Comment: The path given in my answer would work if res folder is inside your project. Or you can simply place the xml along with your java file and use this new File("musicDb.xml");

Comment: I've actually tried that.. but it didn't work. It seems the root directory it is searching from is not my `workspace` folder. Is there a way to change the directory it begins its search?

Comment: you need to paste folder structure of your project as well as the xml for me to understand better

Comment: You mean like this? `C:\Users\Giridhaar\workspace\COMP9321Assignment1\res`